# Laravel search across multiple date ranges

Tags: laravel

| id | listing_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-20 | 2023-01-25 |
| 2 | 1 | 2023-02-26 | 2023-02-10 |
| 3 | 1 | 2023-02-11 | 2023-02-20 |
| 4 | 1 | 2023-02-21 | 2023-02-27 |

```php
$listings->whereHas(
    'availabilityCalendar',
    function ($query) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
        $query->where('start_date', '>=', $start_date)
            ->where('end_date', '<=', $end_date);
    })
}
```

Fetch data according to `start_date = 2023-01-23` / `end_date = 2023-02-20` I sent by frontend. The `start_date` and `end_date` values I sent are among the values in the records I wrote above.

If I sent `start_date = 2023-01-01` / `end_date = 2023-02-20` they wouldn't be included. Or if I had submitted the dates `start_date = 2023-01-23` / `end_date = 2024-01-01` they would still not be included.

But if I sent the dates `start_date = 2023-02-01` / `end_date = 2023-02-15` it would have been met.

Can you help with this?

Comment: one of your data has end_date lower/earlier than start_date, is that correct ?

Comment: get you add extra information on which data are fetched based on given start_date & end_date ?

Comment: you should add ``00:00:00`` after start date and ``23:59:59`` to end date it should work. As:  ``$query->where('start_date', '>=', $start_date . ' 00:00:00')->where('end_date', '<=', $end_date . ' 23:59:59');``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure your query are casted as date.

You can do some thing like

```
$startDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $start_date);
$endDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',  $end_date);

$query->whereDate('start_date', '>=', $startDate )
    ->whereDate('end_date', '<=', $endDate );
```

or

```
$query->where(DB::raw('DATE(start_date)'), '>=', $startDate )
    ->where(DB::raw('DATE(end_date)'), '<=', $endDate );
```